# Save sheets as CSV - ignoring hidden sheets or sheets with macros

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export-to-csv

I need to save all sheets as CSV files with the exception of four hidden sheets ("chip", "play", "other", & "offers") and the sheet which contains the macro buttons ("Magic Buttons").

This code save all sheets. I do not know where to go from here (despite trial and error and reading some other Stack Overflow questions).

```
Sub SaveSheets()
'
' SaveSheets Macro
' Saves sheets as individual CSV files
'
Dim csvPath As String
csvPath = "C:\Daily Batch Files"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `If xWs.Name <> "chip" And xWs.Name <> "play" And xWs.Name <> "Other" And xWs.Name <> "offers" Then`.

Comment: Or `if xWs.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then` - but you'd still need to refer to the Magic Buttons sheet by name then.

Comment: Hi, wondering what I'm doing wrong here as I'm getting an error 404.

`If xWs.Visible = xlSheetVisible And xWs.Name <> "Magic Buttons" Then
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If
End Sub`

Comment: An alternative to the solution @BigBen used is `Select Case xWs.Name` and then `Case "chip"` etc. Have each case have no content, and then the default case is to save as CSV. This lets you just add in sheet names if they ever change, and I like the format's readability a little more. Both solutions work fine though.

Comment: Move that line *inside* the `For` loop (also move the `End If` inside too

Comment: Wow! Thanks @BigBen, that's the issue I'd been having.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions for saving need to go inside the loop.

Using `If...End If`

```vb
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If xWs.Name <> "chip" And xWs.Name <> "play" And _
        xWs.Name <> "Other" And xWs.Name <> "offers" And _
        xWs.Name <> "Magic Buttons" Then

        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
Next
```

Using `Select Case...End Select`

```vb
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case xWs.Name
        Case "chip", "play", "Other", "offers", "Magic Buttons"
        Case Else
            xWs.Copy
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: @BigBen efficient refactor, as always